# Let $A = \{(x_i) \in \ell^1 \mid \lim_{i \to \infty} i^2x_i = 0 \}$. Is $A$ closed in $\ell^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A = \{(x_i) \in \ell^1 \mid \lim_{i \to \infty} i^2x_i = 0 \}$. Is $A$ closed in $\ell^1$?

$A$ is closed if for any convergent sequence in it the limit is also in $A$. I think it's easier for me to understand a sequence of sequences as sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ where $f_1 = (f_1(x), f_2(x), \dots)$ and $x \in \Bbb N$.

So if $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions such that $f_n \to f \in A$, then I need to show that $f \in A$.

So if $\|f_n - f\|_1 \to 0$, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that for $n \ge n_0$ we have that $$\|f_n - f\|_1 < \varepsilon$$

can we deduce from here that $f \in A$ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the sequence $(x_n)$ by $x^k_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k^2}\quad 1\le k\le n\\
0 \quad k>n
\end{cases}$

Then, $x_n\in A$ for each integer $n$ and the sequence converges to $x=(1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\cdots,)\in \ell_1$ but $x\notin A$

so $A$ is not closed in $\ell_1.$

To show $A$ is dense in $\ell_1,$ take an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of an arbitrary $x\in \ell_1,$ note that there is an integer $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N}^\infty |x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and define $y\in A$ by

$y_k=\begin{cases}
x_k \quad 1\le k\le N\\
0 \quad k>N
\end{cases}$

Then, $\|x-y\|_1<\epsilon.$

Comment: If not mistaken is $x^k_n$ defined as $$x^1 = (1, 0, 0, \dots), x^2 = (1, 1/4, 0,0, \dots), x^3 = (1,1/4, 1/9, 0, 0, \dots), x^4 = (1,1/4, 1/9, 1/16, 0 ,0, \dots)?$$ @matematleta

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: In your density argument, how did you conclude that there exists $N$ for which $\sum_{k=N}^\infty |x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?

Comment: $x$ is $\ell_1$ so the tail of the sequence can be made arbitrarily small.